# Trying to implement Flagged Bubble Sort in MIPS

Tags: sorting, mips

I'm trying to implement the Flagged Bubble Sort algorithm in MIPS, following this C++ code:

```
void bubbleSortV2(int a[ ], int n)    //  flagged bubble sort
{
    int i, temp, comps, sorted = 0; //  sorted is initially false
    comps = n – 1;

    while ( !sorted )           //  comps reduces on each pass
    {
        sorted = 1;     //  set true for each pass
        for  (i = 0; i < comps; i++)‏
        {
            if  (a[i] > a[i + 1])‏
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = temp;
                sorted = 0; //  not yet sorted
            }
        }   //  end of each pass
        comps--;
    }   //  end all passes
}
```

My try in MIPS:

```
    li $v0, 0
    la $t1, array

    li $s3, 0 #i=0
    move $s4, $t0 #n
    sub $s4, $s4, 1 #n--
    li $s7, 0; #flag=0
    start:
        beq $s7, 0, stop #flag==1 we stop
        sort:
            li $s7, 1; #set flag=1
            bge $s3, $s4, endsort # while i<n
            lw $t2, 0($t1) #load first element
            lw $t3, 4($t1) #load second element
            bge $t2, $t3, swap #if first > second swap
        go_next:
            add $t1, $t1, 4 #next element
            sub $s4, $s4, 1 #n--
            bgtz $s4, start #if s4>0 we do it again
            swap:
                sw $s5, 4($t1) # swap elements
                sw $s6, 0($t1) #swap elements
                li $s7, 0; #set flag 0
        j go_next # next element
                add $s3, $s3, 1 #i++
        j sort # sort
        endsort:
    stop:
```

I tried my best to follow the high language code but it doesn't work. The output is the same as the input. Can i get some help?

Answer (score 1):

You have at least four problems:

First, your code for `for (i = 0; i < comps; i++)` is missing the `i = 0` part.  While you do have an `i = 0` somewhere, having it in the wrong place doesn't count.  You have it outside all loops, and as you can see the `for` is inside the `while` — therefore the C code does `i = 0` inside the `while` loop, but your assembly doesn't, so it won't behave the same.

Second, your if-then statement doesn't follow a good pattern in assembly.  A good pattern for if-then in assembly's if-goto-label style is:

Pseudo C code:

```
if ( condition ) {
    do something;
}
// if statement completed, on to whatever statement comes next
```

---

in assembly's if-goto-label style (though still using pseudo C):

```
    if ( ! condition ) goto ifEnd;
    do something;
ifEnd:
    // if statement completed, on to whatever statement comes next
```

Detail the exact control flow of the C code and make your assembly have the same control flow.  Don't try to use an alternate control flow from the C code.

---

There are other patterns to implement if-then but most alternate forms make it very easy to loose the proper perspective that this if-then is nested within the for loop — and it is this nesting in the C code that specifies what statement (fragment) comes after the if-then *whether the if-then fires or not*.  Hopefully, you can see if you use the above pattern in assembly's if-goto-label style that the proper next statement will run next *whether or not the if fires*.

---

While your code is not that far from correct, don't be afraid to start over.  If you do use more rigor — stick to the C code, and its nested constructs (the if should be fully inside the for, what comes next after the if-then, etc).

Stick to doing piece parts in the same order that the C code does them — don't try to rearrange piece parts of code (until you know what you're doing, then).

Don't get stuck thinking your only option is to guess how to fix broken assembly code, as that can be *very* difficult.

---

You are using registers `$s5` and `$s6`, but never putting anything in them.

---

Any code in between an unconditional branch and the next label is unreachable,

```
    j somewhere123

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, helloworld
    syscall

somelabel456:
```

In the above, the syscall code between `j somewhere123` and `somelabel456:` is definitely unreachable, and hence "dead", i.e. never used; serving no possible purpose.